# Using SQLAlchemy Automap with Amazon Aurora

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, amazon-aurora

I have a legacy MySQL database in Amazon Aurora that I want to use with SQLAlchemy Automap.

I'm running the following versions:

```
15:09 $ pip freeze
appnope==0.1.0
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
decorator==4.0.10
enum34==1.1.6
ipython==5.1.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
mysql==0.0.1
MySQL-python==1.2.5
pathlib2==2.1.0
pexpect==4.2.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
prompt-toolkit==1.0.9
ptyprocess==0.5.1
Pygments==2.1.3
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.1.3
traitlets==4.3.1
wcwidth==0.1.7
```

And this code:

```
import os
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = automap_base()
cs = os.environ['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']
engine = create_engine(cs)
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```

but on the prepare call I get the following exception:

```
1925         except exc.DBAPIError as e:
1926             if self._extract_error_code(e.orig) == 1146:
-> 1927                 raise exc.NoSuchTableError(full_name)
1928             else:
1929                 raise

NoSuchTableError: `role`
```

Is there a driver for SQLAlchemy that can account for the differences in Aurora or does this indicate that there's a real problem with the schema?